# My on_member_join isn't sending the welcome message

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So, I'm making a bot for a server I'm in, and am trying to add a welcome message for when a member joins. So far, It hasn't been working, and no errors have been given. Is there something wrong with it?

```
async def on_member_join(member):
    print("working") #I have this here to check to see if its being called, but no message is printed.
    rules = client.get_channel(772263419210235916)
    verify = client.get_channel(772995392521895937)
    channel = client.get_channel(772583213797212211)
    embed=discord.Embed(title="Welcome to Delight Stuidos!",
                        description=f"""{member.mention} has joined! \nDon't forget to read the {rules.mention}, and react with the purple star in {verify.mention}!
                        Enjoy your stay ^^""",
                        color = discord.Colour.orange())
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=f"https://i.ibb.co/NC2Wgnk/DS.png")
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Also have intends enabled, so I don't know whats up.

Comment: do you have `intents.members` enabled?

Comment: Yeah, I enabled them

Answer (score 0):

Changed a few things that might cause errors

```
async def on_member_join(member):
    try:
        print("working") #I have this here to check to see if its being called, but no message is printed.
        rules = member.guild.get_channel(772263419210235916)
        verify =  member.guild.get_channel(772995392521895937)
        channel =  member.guild.get_channel(772583213797212211)
        embed=discord.Embed(title="Welcome to Delight Stuidos!",
                        description=f"{member.mention} has joined! \nDon't forget to read the {rules.mention}, and react with the purple star in {verify.mention}!\n Enjoy your stay ^^",
                        color = discord.Colour.orange())
        embed.set_thumbnail(url="https://i.ibb.co/NC2Wgnk/DS.png")
        await channel.send(embed=embed)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Comment: Argh, that didn't work either- It didn't send the e or print anything

Comment: @Wackamole maybe try get rid of the .set_thumbnail and try as no error is being generated